# difference of length - JTextField/date

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I have an error type difference of length.
Why?

```
private void txtMoisActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    java.util.Date date1 = jDateChooserDateDebut.getDate();
    java.util.Date date2 = jDateChooserDateFin.getDate();
    long CONST_DURATION_OF_DAY = 1000l * 60 * 60 * 24;

    long diff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    long numberOfMonths = diff/CONST_DURATION_OF_DAY;
    txtMois.setText() = this.numberOfMonts;
    affiche ("txtMois" + numberOfMonths);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but please, don't calculate time using basic arithmetic, there are way to many edge cases you need to take into account.  Instead, use Java 8's Date/Time API

Comment: `txtMois.setText() = this.numberOfMonts;` ... ?  You can't assign a value to a method, you need to pass it a value.  Also, `setText` expects a `String` so you will need to convert your `Long` value to a `String` - This is all basic skills and knowledge you should already have been trying to embark on complex concepts like GUI and date/time manipulation

Comment: I get “The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable”. Isn’t that pretty clear?

Comment: (1) Always use uppercase `L` for a long value, it’s so easy to misread lowercase `l` for digit `1`. (2) The `Date` class is long outdated, use `LocalDate` from `java.time` instead. (3) Then use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()` to calculate the duration.

Comment: If you cannot get `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()` to work, my guess is you have (accidentally?) used `LocalDate` from Joda-Time and `ChronoUnit` from `java.time`. They are not compatible. You may want to edit your question and add your import statements for verification.

Comment: Do you want the difference in days or in months (mois)?

Answer (score 0):

I have not got experience with `JCalendar` nor `JDateChooser`, and I have not tried to compile the following code, so bear with me if there’s a typo or bug.

As I read [the documentation of `JDateChooser`](http://javadox.com/com.toedter/jcalendar/1.4/doc/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html), it can give you an old-fashioned `java.util.Calendar` and a `java.util.Date`, but unfortunately not a modern `java.time.LocalDate`. A `Date` is a point in time, so converting it to a date is fragile since it is never the same date everywhere on the globe. So to make the conversion correctly we need the time zone. Fortunately, the `Calendar` can give that to us, directly or indirectly.

So I believe you should try

```
LocalDate dateDebut = ((GregorianCalendar) jDateChooserDateDebut.getCalendar()).toZonedDateTime()
        .toLocalDate();
```

And similarly for `jDateChooserDateFin`/ `dateFin`. I am assuming that the `Calendar` object returned from `getCalendar()` is really a `GregorianCalendar`, which it almost certainly is. If you get a `ClassCastException`, we need to use `Calendar.getTimeZone​()` instead, it will be a bit more complicated and cumbersome, I hope not and will not go into it for now.

When the above works, it should be possible to continue like this:

```
long dureeLong = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateDebut, dateFin);
String dureeString = String.valueOf(dureeLong);
txtMois.setText(dureeString);
affiche("txtMois: " + dureeString);
```

If instead of days you wanted to count months, I think you’re best off using

```
long numberOfMonths = Period.between(dateDebut, dateFin).toTotalMonths();
```

There are some corner cases if one date is the 29, 30 or 31 of a month and the other month doesn’t have that many days; but generally this will give you the expected result.